# Matplotlib, can't see single non-zero pixel in hi-res image

Tags: matplotlib

I have some 1000x1000 images where one pixel is 1 and the rest 0.  My issue is that I can't even see the location of the high pixel using imshow() unless I zoom in all over the place to look for it. I assume it is doing a nearest lookup when decimating to screen resolution.  Is there any trick I can use to get around this?  I know I can convolve with a kernel of some kind to expand the point, but this is a little bit expensive computationally, and if I zoom in it won't look correct.

Comment: Just plot a dot at the location where the pixel is.

Comment: Yeah, that's a simple workaround.  I'll go that route for my current problem.  I have had similar issues with high resolution imagery though, where the amplitude and number of peaks is unknown.  The custom renderers do a max operation when resolution is reduced for display, but I haven't found an easy substitute in python or matlab.

Comment: yes oddly enough changing the interp argument to imshow will do the kernel thing for you, but in c so it’s pretty fast.  Using interp=hanning should help.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13724